# get id to my first resource and filter the id to my second resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

for example i have this json data

```
sampledataA = [
  {"id": 1,"employee_id": 1},
  {"id": 2,"employee_id": 1},
  {"id": 3,"employee_id": 1},
  {"id": 4,"employee_id": 2},
  {"id": 5,"employee_id": 2},
  {"id": 6,"employee_id": 2}
  {"id": 7,"employee_id": 3},
  {"id": 8,"employee_id": 3},
  {"id": 9,"employee_id": 3}]

sampleDataB = [
  {"employee_id": 1, "name":"Name1"},
  {"employee_id": 2, "name": "Name2"},
  {"employee_id": 3, "name": "Name3"}]
```

in my controller i need to get the the employee_id in SampleDataA then filter the employee ids to my sampleDataB to get there name is this possible to this in the controller??

Answer (score 1):

`let id = 1; //whatever you are looking for...
let employee_id = sampledataA.find(x => x.id === id).employee_id;
let name = sampledataB.find(x => x.employee_id === employee_id).name;`

is that what you are asking about?

Comment: yes but i need to populate all name in my sampledataA, in my view i ng-repeat the sampledataA with unique employee id, but i need to get the name not the id thanks for answering my question..and sorry for my wrong grammar XD

Comment: i guess you can do something like this: `sampledataA.forEach(item => {item.name = sampledataB.find(x => x.employee_id === item.employee_id).name});`

Comment: yes. whatever you are doing though - data manipulation like that is better to be done in the back end